# Getting a container div over another (bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Okej, so im trying to get one div container over another in bootstrap.

This is the html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

</div>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

And this is the css i got so far:

```
.container-fluid{
    height: 400px;
    background: black; 
    z-index: -10;
}

.container{
    height: 800px;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

So what i want is for the .container to be ontop of the .container-fluid. Is there an easy way of doing this or does anyone know a better method? The container-fluid is suppose to contain an image that will be the page header in the future, while the container will be the site contet.
The reason i want the container over the container-fluid is so that the the text i write in the beginning will be displayed on the header and keep a good position as the screen size gets smaller.

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 5):

use:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
```

for your container and wrap both div's into another div with position:relative. (or add position:relative to whatever parent both div's share)

as this: http://jsfiddle.net/0p8s1omp/

Comment: That makes the container div as wide as the container-fluid. I still need the container to be less wide then the container-fluid!

Comment: Well, get rid of width:100% (which I add just so you would be able to see the div) but you need to write something inside the div to actually see anything: http://jsfiddle.net/0p8s1omp/1/.. or just add the width you want it to be...

Comment: http://imgur.com/SMMo9ie
It only looks like this now. It isn't in the center of the black div!